# How to detect when an R function with system command is done then start running the next function?

Tags: r, linux, macos

I have to use two functions in an R package and put them in a script to run the processes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(pkg)

function1()
function2()
```

Both function 1 & 2 includes `system()` command to run some bash scripts. `function2` needs the output from `function1` as input.

The problem is when I run the above script in macOS or Ubuntu, both functions run at the same time so `function2` would raise errors. I wonder if there's any way in R not to trigger `function2` until `function1` is done?

Comment: The default for `system()` is `wait=TRUE` so the first function should not return until the system call is finished. Can you provide some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to show that's not the case? Are you sure you're not running the script more than once?

Comment: hmmm thanks I think you're right, I guess it's my local machine's setup is not good then the software in the first function can't even run for quite a while...
I will change another machine and test my stuff again and see